# Recursivly search array and sum field

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function that will iterate over an array of arrays and sum a specific field.  Here is an example of an array:

```
{
  "68": {
    "10": [
      {
        "id": "3333",
        "sumTHis": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  "69": {
    "45": [
      {
        "id": "3333",
        "sumTHis": "5"
      }
    ],
    "50": [
      {
        "id": "3330",
        "sumTHis": "5"
      },
      {
        "id": "3331",
        "sumTHis": "5"
      },
      {
        "id": "3332",
        "sumTHis": "5"
      },
      {
        "id": "3333",
        "sumTHis": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that the array could be any number of sub-arrays deep. In the end, I would like to be able to sum all "sumTHis" nodes throughout the entire array The code I have so far is this:

```
//in body
$sumThis= recurse_get_total($array, 'sumTHis');


//recursive function
function recurse_get_total($report_data, $valId, $total = 0){
    try{
            foreach ($report_data as $key => $value) {
                if(is_array_of_arrays($value)){
                    recurse_get_total($value, $valId, $total);
                }else{
                   $total = $total + $value[$valId];
                   return $total;
                }
            }
        return $total;
    }catch(Exception $err){
        throw $err;
    }
}

function is_array_of_arrays($isArray){
    try{
        if(is_array($isArray)){
            foreach($isArray as $key => $value){
                if(!is_array($value)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception $err){
        throw $err;
    }
}
```

This function starts to iterate over the array but gets kicked out after the first one and returns 0.  Can anyone help out?

Thanks
jason

Comment: How is recurse_get_total recursive ?

Comment: That is not an array, but a JSON string.

Comment: Yeah, i know its a json string.  I took the array and encoded it to get the array as a string to easily past it into this question

Comment: sorry, abbiya, I had a typo (called my recursed function incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going about this problem I set something up with "array_walk_recursive". Seeing that you want to add some stuff independent of the depth of the arrays, this seems to work.
It is not solving it with what you have, but perhaps this different approach will get you there.

```
$sum = 0;

$array = array(
    "one" => array(
        "day" => "tuesday",
        "week" => "20",
        "findthis" => 10
    ),
    "two" => array("subone" => array(
            "some" => "one",
            "findthis" => 23
        )),
    "deeperthree" => array("subtwo" => array("deeper" => array(
                "one" => "entry",
                "findthis" => 44
            )))
);

function callback($val, $key, $arg) {

    if ($key == "findthis") {
        $arg[0]($val, $arg[1]);
    }

};

$function = function($num, &$sum) {
    $sum = $sum + $num;
    echo $sum . " ";
};

array_walk_recursive($array, "callback", array( $function, &$sum ));
```

**result:** 10 33 77